# "Module does not explicitly reexport attribute" Mypy implicit-reexport

Tags: python, mypy, python-module, python-typing

I have a python library of the following structure:

```
module
 > module_namespace
   __init__.py
   MyClass.py
   > asyncio
     __init__.py
     MyClass.py
```

In the **ini**.py files I have explicitly exported the classes like:

```
# __init__.py
from .MyClass import ClassType
__all__ = ["ClassType"]
```

Then, I import it from another application

```
from module_namespace import ClassType
# Or 
# from module_namespace.asyncio import ClassType
```

However, mypy complains that the module does not reexport "ClassType".
I have a `mypy.ini` with `implicit_reexport=false`, which I don't want to change. And my understanding was that adding the `__all__` was enough to reexport the symbols. Anyone knows what I could be doing wrong?